# VB.Net detecting SHIFT key on datagridview editing control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a editing control that `Inherits myTextBox` this `Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl`.

I know that if the editing control handles a key event it should be inside the `Function EditingControlWantsInputKey`, therefore I added the below code.

```
Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        If key = Keys.ShiftKey Then
            Return True
        End If
End Function
```

The keycode associated with the the `Keys.ShiftKey` is 16, but I used a MsgBox(key) to find out the keycode & it prints out 65552. I am trying to detect the shift key to allow users to hightlight text inside a textbox using SHIFT+ARROW_RIGHT/LEFT. At the moment when I press SHIFT+RIGHT/LEFT the cursor moves to the next cell because the SHIFT key is not detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keydata/key param is the bitwise value of *any or all* of the modifier keys pressed (Ctrl+A, Shift+Left, Shift+Control+Right etc).  The value `65552` indicates that `Keys.Shift` is true (ie the Shift key is being pressed) and modifying input.

For Shift+Left, the value would be 65573  (`65536 Or 37`):

```
If (keydata And Keys.Shift) = Keys.Shift AndAlso
      (keydata And keys.Left) = Keys.Left Then     ' ToDo: add Keys.Right

   Return True
End If
Return False ' MSDN: Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
```

`Keys.ShiftKey` is a key (16)  while `Keys.Shift` (65536) is a modifier for Shift or Control or Alt.

Comment: Ok now my code looks like this, is this correct ?
If key = Keys.Right OrElse key = Keys.Left OrElse (key And Keys.Shift) = Keys.Shift Then Return True

Comment: And why do you return false rather than Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey

Comment: to trap either, it should  be: *If (Shift clause) AndAlso ((Left clause ) Or (Right clause)) = Then*  AndAlso means do evaluate the rest if false, then you want Shift and either (left or Right). `Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey` might be correct, I didnt have a DGV handy to test I think they would be the same.